# Figure is not properly positioned

Tags: floats, revtex

I am using the aps revtex4-1 layout. For eight times, I included a figure through `\begin(figure)[h]` and they all were properly positioned. Although I followed the same procedure for Fig. 9, the figure gets placed under section "Analysis of Circular Polarization", even though I have clearly declared it *before the declaration of the section*. Any help in trying to remedy this issue would be appreciated. [image]

Comment: [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)

Comment: @Mico -- Thank you. The `\usepackage` worked. But, why is it that for the last 8 figures I didnt have any issues? I was using the same exact commands.

Comment: Perhaps because there was not enough space for it in the column above IV. Remember "h" does not mean "here!"

Comment: Wow, I always thought "h" meant here, as in force the image to this immediate location. What does it mean? and how do you force the image to be "here"?

Comment: The only point of the `figure` environment is to let it change position. If you want to force it somewhere, use `[H]` from package float, but this makes using a floating figure quite nonsense.

Comment: I mostly deal with single column docs, in them "h" means *here if possible*, where it is also understood that in order to be a *here* float there needs to be text above and below (otherwise it is a top or a bottom float). Many (new) users get this wrong. Things a a little more complicated in two column docs. In general consider using "htbp"  (perhaps leaving out the "b") and get to terms with latex placing the float as close to where you placed it as it can.